# No air coming in through vents - Can't find blower motor to troubleshoot it

Tags: hvac, repair, furnace

I'm a relatively new townhome-owner and I'm troubleshooting a furnace issue. My home isn't heated, and more specifically, air does not flow through the vents despite turning on the fan via thermostat. I watched about an hour's worth of videos to get a basic idea of furnace functionality and startup, and noticed that my control board status light is a constant red, but that meant normal conditions for my model.

I tried observing my furnace startup process and I set the thermostat to a higher temp with fan set to On. I hear a click, and then furnace turning on, I see the pilot light ignite, and the inducer motor spinning. I ended up watching for a couple minutes and the pilot light stays on and the motor is still spinning, so I don't think it's short-cycling. I wait a couple minutes longer, but in the end, there's no warm air being pumped through the vents.

My model is a Goodman GPD050-3 forced air furnace. From the videos, it seems that lack of air through vents means I should check out the blower motor and/or air filters, but I cannot find where those are located in my furnace. Maybe I'm missing something about how my furnace is set up and I need to look for more specific videos/guides on repair? Thanks!

[image: Front of furnace]

[image: Side of furnace]

Comment: What blink codes are you getting on the control board?

Comment: Currently solid red. According to the table in the furnace, this is one of two issues:

1. Constant: None

2. Continuous: Incorrect twinning, check polarity

I'm not sure whether a solid red light would be constant or continuous though

Comment: When looking up other Goodman furnace issues, it appears that "Continuous" refers to a continuous blinking/flashing light, and what I have is "Constant" so the diagnostic light isn't helpful in this scenario

Comment: "the pilot light ignite, and the inducer motor spinning" and then what happens? You get a flame for two seconds? Then clean the flame sensor. - Otherwise the gas valve isn't opening; or there's no gas to it.

Comment: Where do you replace your air filter?  Or are you filtered at the return?

Comment: Please revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. What it's currently asking isn't particularly helpful to us _or_ you. I suggest asking about your actual problem instead.

Comment: Thanks above folks for taking a look and leaving a comment, I updated the title/question where possible. There's an vent cover in the ceiling for an air filter, so I believe I'm filtered at the return, but not 100% sure

Comment: @Mazura could also be a pressure sensor problem. Checking the sequence in the manual will give the best troubleshooting steps.

Comment: Sometimes the right solution is to call someone who works on such things professionally, rather than attepting DIY well out of your depth. Incidentally, the location of the water heater seems rather hostile to furnace maintenance, here.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Last time I had an issue, l called a professional for something that ended up being quite simple, so I wanted to do due diligence and perhaps learn more about my home along the way.

Answer (score 2):

I'm gonna guess the blower is here.

[image]

Those wires top right are for *something*.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look - I assumed those wires were for the heat exchange at the back of the furnace, but I definitely should take a closer look at that portion after work. Thanks!